# Division of columns, based on their names

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a DataFrame with lots of columns and some of them have the names like these: `total_act_qty`, `total_act_usd_amt`. I.e. having a `qty` and `usd_amt` parts with the same beginning.
There are also another columns with `qty` and `amt` in their names, but without corresponding pairs.
I would like to create a new column for every such pair with calculation of the quotient from division *amt/qty*

Here is an example of DF:

```
pd.DataFrame({'total_act_qty':range(1,5),
              'total_act_usd_amt':range(3,7),
              'total_1y_act_usd_amt':range(11,15),
              'total_1y_act_qty':[np.nan, 1, 2, 3],
              'cc_tmp_qty':range(0,8,2),
              'new_col':['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan]
             })
```

i've started from getting the lists of needed cols, and then stuck

```
lst = train.columns
lst_qty = [i for i in lst if i.find('qty')>-1]
lst_amt = [i for i in lst if i.find('usd_amt')>-1]
```

Will be thankful for any ideas of the ways of solving this problem

I'm thinking about comparison of these two lists and getting correct pairs and then applying a function using it.. Don't know the way to realise it( Or may be there is better solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, SO is not a free code writing service. Please view [ask] and create a [mcve], as well as share your attempt at solving your own problem!

Comment: got it! will add a code example in a minute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741769/calculate-multiple-columns-by-names-using-python-pandas For a problem like this, you should consider having a MultiIndex on the columns, which makes aligning these types of operations much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `list` comprehension to get the prefixes that generate columns ending with both `'usd_amt'` and `'qty'`, and then create a new dataframe with `assign`:

```
qty_cols = (col.replace('_qty', '') for col in df.columns if col.endswith('qty'))
use_cols = [col for col in qty_cols if f'{col}_usd_amt' in df.columns]

result = df.assign(**{f'{col}_result': df[f'{col}_usd_amt'] / df[f'{col}_qty'] for col in use_cols})

print(result)
```

Output:

```
   total_act_qty  total_act_usd_amt  total_1y_act_usd_amt  total_1y_act_qty  \
0              1                  3                    11               NaN   
1              2                  4                    12               1.0   
2              3                  5                    13               2.0   
3              4                  6                    14               3.0   

   cc_tmp_qty new_col  total_act_result  total_1y_act_result  
0           0       a          3.000000                  NaN  
1           2       b          2.000000            12.000000  
2           4       c          1.666667             6.500000  
3           6     NaN          1.500000             4.666667
```

Comment: Never knew we could use formatted strings like this! 
And double asterics is also a magic for me now.
thanks a lot!

Comment: @DenisKa f-strings are only available in Python >= 3.6 though, so you will need to switch to `.format` calls for earlier version.